# What are possible ways to dynamically analyze windows service?

Tags: windows, dynamic-analysis, executable, ollydbg

I am working executable, which is meant to be loaded as windows service. I have statically determine certain breakpoints that I'd like it to break upon execution. Is there any particular way to dynamically analyze this executable with OllyDBG?
What are general approaches to dynamically analyzing windows service?

Comment: Already answered at http://reverseengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/2019/debugging-malware-that-will-only-run-as-a-service

Comment: Perfect! That is what I was looking for! Thank you!