# Can't debug a service

Tags: ida, ollydbg, debugging, malware, immunity-debugger

I am working on Lab11-03 in "Practical Malware Analysis" book.
The malware I am analyzing trojanized the file `cisvc.exe` which is the indexing service in Windows XP.

After that the malware start the service by running the command `net start cisvc`.
I put a breakpoint before it starts the service:
[image]

I want to debug the service (cisvc.exe).
I opened it in another instance of OllyDbg but I received an exception:
[image]

There is an option to attach processes but the serivce it currently stopped.
I need some way to put a breakpoint in the very beginning of it.

Any idea how can I do it ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it by using updated version of OllyDbg => OllyDbg 2.01

I also found another reference that provides another way to solve such problem in the future:
[Debugging malware that will only run as a service](https://reverseengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/2019/debugging-malware-that-will-only-run-as-a-service)